# Prolog doesn't load files properly

Tags: macos, prolog, load

I am running Prolog on a Mac OS Yosemite.
I trying SWI and GProlog but no luck.
I download the program but how can I load a file ?
Is that so difficult ?
I get error messages when I trying to load.

uncaught exception: `error(existence_error(source_sink,'test.pl'),consult/1)`

Comment: try with the full path to file

Comment: Thank you but how can I take the full path from Macintosh HD 2 for example ?

Comment: Don't you know where your file is stored? I am not familiar with MAC, but I guess some `pwd` command exists.

Comment: It's on my Macintosh HD 2. On Terminal what should I write for the full path ?

Comment: Ok, now it sounds like a joke. By WHERE, I mean the PATH.

Comment: I understand you but unfortunately I don't know where I can find the path. It's not windows system. Also the characters are not all latin in directories.

Comment: `test.pl` is a file, that I gues you have written yourself. Or, at least, downloaded it and dropped somewhere. In either case you should know better than me where you have saved it.

Comment: It needs the full path with single quotes. When the program starts I get error message 

ERROR: /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/library/win_menu.pl:195: Initialization goal raised exception:
ERROR: file_base_name/2: Cannot represent due to `encoding' (Cannot represent char U03a0 using current locale encoding)

Also if I give the command man(X). it shows me only the first man not all the men.
And with consult command I see the error ERROR: Source_sink 'test' does not exist. 

Any ideas ? 
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please update your question to provide examples that include: the current working of your Prolog top-level (in SWI Prolog, the query `?- pwd.` will provide this), the exact query you enter in the attempt to load your file, the actual path to the file you are attempting to load. As for querying `man(X)`, are you entering `;` after the first result in order to retrieve more answers?

Comment: FYI, the basic operation of loading files is very straight forward and painless in SWI Prolog. If you are running into trouble, it is either because there is something amiss with your setup (environment variables, your version of Prolog, encoding conflicts, etc.) or a gap in your understanding of how to use the tools.

Comment: @aBathologist 
How can I upload a picture to show the errors ?

Comment: @Giannis You can cut and paste the contents of your terminal sessions, including the commands and errors. It is not common (not especially helpful) to share such information vis screen shots. But if you need to for some reason you can just upload an image to any image hosting site and provide a link here.

Comment: @aBathologist
ERROR: /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/library/win_menu.pl:195: Initialization goal raised exception:
ERROR: file_base_name/2: Cannot represent due to `encoding' (Cannot represent char U03a0 using current locale encoding)
...............................................

ERROR: file_base_name/2: Cannot represent due to `encoding' (Cannot represent char U03a0 using current locale encoding)
1 ?-

Comment: @Giannis what command are you entering before receiving this error?

Comment: @aBathologist I just open the program and I can see this error at the first line.

Comment: @Giannis Oh I see. I thought you were trying to load a file into the top level. The error you are receiving looks to be an issue that Prolog is having with the character encoding in the base name of a file. I recommend posting your issue to the SWI discussion forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swi-prolog They will likely have an idea of how to approach the problem. Provide as much info as possible: SWI version number, operating system version, the precise way you are trying to launch SWI Prolog, etc. Sorry I don't know how to help more!

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a temporary (or not ?) solution.
It needs to open the program from the terminal with this command :
-a /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app (this worked for me).
If you want to load a file just use the full path with single quotes :
['/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/Informatics/Prolog/Programs/test'].
(test is the file which I want to load)
Thank you @Eugene Sh. - thank you @aBathologist.

Answer (score 2):

[Giannis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28745319) didn't work for me but I found another solution:

I first exited out of Prolog and went into the terminal, then used the commands:

```
touch filename.pl
open filename.pl
```

and it opened the file. Then I went back into Prolog and `[filename].` worked.